# Auto sizing UICollectionViewCells

Tags: ios

I'm trying to find an elegant way of doing auto sizing of `UICollectionViewCell` objects.

I understand that this topic has been covered a fair bit, in the form of blog posts and SO questions. In spite of that, I've yet come across an elegant solution.

For example, here are the steps to getting an auto resizing `UITableViewCell` to resize based on the vertical length of a single `UILabel`:

1. Make sure there are vertical spacing constraints from the `contentView` to the `UILabel`.
2. Set the `rowHeight` property to `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`
3. Set the `estimatedRowHeight` property

I am hoping I can follow through these steps for the `UICollectionView`. Here's what I've done so far:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
  @IBOutlet private var collectionView: UICollectionView!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewLayout
    layout.itemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayoutAutomaticSize
    Layout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.width, height: 100)
  }
}
```

Currently, this automatically resizes horizontally. What I really want is to micmic the `UITableView` resizing and have it auto size vertically.

Does anyone have a solution to do this?

Comment: It might help you. https://possiblemobile.com/2016/02/sizing-uicollectionviewcell-fit-multiline-uilabel/